# Possible merge account request

Tags: support

I'm new to SO and Stack Exchange in general. I noticed that on MetaStackOverlow, my user id is one of the auto-generated ones, but on SO I have a real user name (Green Giant). But when I go to my profile and click "network profile", the Stack Exchange profile page shows by SO user.

So my question is: Are my accounts already merged/linked, but just show a different user name between SO and MSO, or are they separate and need to be merged?

If the latter, then I'd like a moderator to merge my accounts please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current profile is already linked with [Stack Overflow's one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/539048/).

Go on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/539048/greengiant?tab=accounts) page and hit <kbd>Copy Stack Overflow profile to all Stack Exchange accounts</kbd> to automatically change your name